# Callbacks how to pass bool

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, mediator

I have a project (WCF, XAML, C#), and in this project I have a mediator class (which follows the mediator pattern). It allows classes to register for callbacks when certain actions have been completed (for example data loading from a database).

The 'Register' method for the mediator looks as follows:

```
public void Register(Action<Object> callback, ViewModelMessages message)
    {
        internalList.AddValue(message, callback);
    }
```

Then the classes that register are notified at certain points, whereby the callbacks are called. This all works fine.

The problem is when I attempt to pass a variable of type bool when an action is completed. In this particular case, I want a message to be passed using this mediator pattern to say when a certain edit is happening (user input editing of data). It should just pass along 'true' or 'false'. So, a boolean type you would think.

The registration on the side of the class that wants to receive the message is as so:

```
Mediator.Mediator.Instance.Register(
            (Object o) =>
            {
                // o is boolean
                if (o == null)
                    return;

                if ((o as bool) == true)
                    // Editing in progress
                else
                    // Editing over ");
            }, Mediator.Mediator.ViewModelMessages.EditCharacterMode);
```

Now what it tells me, is that this object, 'o' can't be a bool because a bool is not nullable.

I feel like I could tackle this in an ugly way like making a class with just a bool in it or something like that, but since this is surely something that comes up frequently, I would like to know if there is a graceful or more accepted solution to this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: if (o is bool) ....

Comment: Why not use Action<bool> ?  (or am I missing something?)

Comment: This is a possibility, but I use this type of callback for more things than just bool. So then I'd need another Register method which took Action<bool> and another list which held Action<bool>. Or I could use Generics, but then I'd have two instances of the mediator class.

Both work, but I'm not sure either are ideal.

Comment: You'll probably get a better conversation on this at [stack code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/): this is a design question which doesn't have a right/wrong answer.